# Remove lighting effects

Tags: materials, light

I have a plane with an object coming out of it. No materials are assigned. I placed a Point light in front of the scene, illuminating the whole surface. You can clearly notice a difference between the two surfaces.

[image: example]

How can I disable those differences? I am building a virtual model in which no light scattering should be present. I want the materials to behave equally if exposed to the same light (like a perfect projector).

I tried with different materials with no success.

EDIT: I am projecting some light pattern onto the surface. So I want the material to evenly reflect the pattern, without any scattering/shadow.

If I usa a RGB input (thanks to @Christopher Bennett) the material does not interact with projected light. E.g. the central object does not reflect the yellow chessboard pattern like:
[image: Not reflecting]

Instead I want the chessboard to be "stamped" on the object, again with no other light effect.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? - just plug an RGB input into the Material output. This is what you could call "unshaded", there will be no shadows or light scattering of any kind.

[image: Unshaded]

Comment: Thanks. I should be more precise: I am projecting a light pattern on the surface. I want this pattern to be reflected by the material with no scattering/shadows.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Christopher Bennett could be the right one, depending on what you're doing.
I was unclear in the question (see edit above).

The solution for me was to assign a Diffuse BSDF material to the objects with roughness=1. This way I got the effect I wanted:

[image]

You can see that the object is still there (lines are not straight).